# $elemMatch query in looback-angularjs sdk with loopback-mongodb-connector?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

I have a collection called Dish in mongodb the sample data is -

```
[{
"_id": ObjectId("56c839b969431a9913cafa65"),
"name": "Dish 01",
"description": "Dish 01 description",
"ingredients": [{
    "id": "56c4a40bf97c039d44e89185",
    "name": "onion",
}, {
    "id": "56c4a40bf97c039d44e89145",
    "name": "salt",
}, {
    "id": "56c4a40bf97c039d44e89176",
    "name": "spices",
}],
"category": "entree",
"image": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sichu-bucket/2016-02-20T13:10:31.334Zapi.js"
}, {
"_id": ObjectId("56c839b969431a9913cafa70"),
"name": "Dish 02",
"description": "Dish 02 description",
"ingredients": [{
    "id": "56c4a40bf97c039d44e89185",
    "name": "onion",
}, {
    "id": "56c4a40bf97c039d44e89145",
    "name": "oil",
}],
"category": "main",
"image": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sichu-bucket/2016-02-20T13:10:31.334Zapi.js"
}]
```

now I want dishes which has **onion** in it and I want to get result by using **loopback-angularjs-sdk**

I have added this to my Dish.json file

```
"settings": {
    "mongodb": {
      "allowExtendedOperators": true
    }
}
```

I don't know how it should be done. Please guide me into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ngApp controller pass the Dish object, and then you can use the Dish.find filter to create a filter api, which will internally search mongo for all the dishes with indegredients as onion.

```
Dish.find({"filter": {"where": {"indegredients.id": "56c4a40bf97c039d44e89185"}}}, function (dishes) {
});
```

For more on filter api, or how to call them through angular sdk you can use.
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK

Plus you can run a local server for the loopback angular sdk documentation also.

For generating the angular sdk documentation, what you can do is

```
lb-ng-doc client/js/services/lb-services.js
```

Browse the documentation at http://localhost:3030/

Comment: Thanks @Nishant i'll try this. Can you give some more details about how can I run a local server for the loopback angular sdk documentation? This be very helpful.

Comment: it is very simple, lb-ng-doc client/js/lb-services.js and then you can access it at http://localhost:3030/

Comment: i tried this **lb-ng-doc client/src/libraries/lb-services.js** as my lb services is in other place. but didn't work it says -------- verifying plugins --------
and then nothing happens.